# x86 Assembly , stack push instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, callstack, machine-code, opcode

I just found out that the push instruction can have an immediate byte , word , dword arguments and each of these have different opcodes. There were no examples in the book I was reading so I don't understand how the assembler differentiates between these three types. For example , if I write `push 12h` how will it be interpreted by the assembler and what will actually happen on the stack?

Comment: Surely the *entire purpose* of an assember is to figure out the sequence of opcodes that correspond to your input. Give it some credit.

Comment: +1 For asking this before I did! I'll give NASM some credit :-)

Comment: word vs. dword push have the same opcode; only an operand-size prefix selects which one you get.  Near duplicate: [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45127993) which explains that operand-size is separate from immediate width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's up to the assembler. It may pick the opcode with the smallest operand field large enough to hold the immediate value. It may also require you to tell it which variant you want to use.

For example, NASM will assemble `push 12h` into `6A 12` (`push byte 12h`).

If you wanted e.g. to get the `push imm16` variant you'd say `push strict word 12h` (`strict` is necessary if you don't want NASM to optimize the instruction into a byte push).

Note that an immediate byte `push` doesn't actually push a byte onto the stack. The value will be sign-extended to at least 16 bits before being pushed (this happens during execution, not during compilation).

Comment: Is there a reason for having an immediate byte instruction if it extends the byte to a word or dword anyway ?

Comment: I had two comments on this which I withdraw and redo for others interest: When I compiled "push 1" in Gnu AS, it turns into the push imm8 instructions "6A01". But this is somewhat misleading - I assumed that it would do something insane like push a byte or a word. But it doesn't, it pushes 32 bits. "push 1" then "pop eax" returns 1 in eax. So, Michael is correct :-)

Comment: @NarekMargaryan: yes, code-size.  `push 1` is only a 2 byte instruction as `push imm8`, not 5 for `push imm32`.  On original 8086 it only saved 1 byte (`imm16` vs. `imm8`) but code size was a critical factor for 8086 and especially 8088: the major bottleneck for performance was code fetch.  So sign-extended imm8 vs. full imm16/32 immediate versions exist for most instructions.  See the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push.  See also [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45127993)

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Your point about code size is correct, but note that the push immediate instructions appeared with the 186 instruction set, not the 8086.

Comment: @ecm: oops, right.  8086 did have `add/sub/xor/... r/m16, imm8` and `imm16` though, so that pattern of having an opcode for sign-extended imm8 as well as full size did come from 8086.

Answer (score 2):

The assembler generates a different opcode for each variant. It will examine the argument before deciding which opcode to assemble to. Because 12h from your example is not a name of a register, but meets the characteristics of hex representation of a number, it concludes that pushing an immediate value is wanted, and generates the corresponding opcode along with the binary value as instruction. It will also examine whether the argument is enclosed by square brackets, for indirection. 
For the CPU, when executing that code, those different variants are de facto different instructions - albeit sharing some commonalities when executed.

Examining the argument(s), to determine their nature, is what the assembler does with many instructions, other than push, too, for the same purpose: deciding which opcode needs to be chosen for the instruction.

Answer (score -2):

In DOS or Windows Debug.com (not Debug.exe at least not in my version), you would say
Push byte 12 or push word 1234.
Push dword 12345678 might also work, for a double word (4 bytes, 32 bits), but I'm not at my PC at this moment so I can't try it